# asp.net mvc session less application, how to pass data between two action

Tags: asp.net, tempdata, session-less

We are working on session less asp.net mvc  application. 
We have a requirement in which we have to pass data between two actions. our application is deployed on multi-server. so I can't be able to use TempData.
As well TempData uses session itself. so that the other reason that I can't use TempData.

What should I do to solve this problem.

I only need the passed data should be used once and expires after reading.

Comment: Someone please help me out